# AR(2) simulation problem

Tags: time-series, simulation, autoregressive

Take covariances $Cov[X_{t-2},X_{t}]$, $Cov[X_{t-1},X_{t}]$ and $Cov[X_t,X_t]=Var[X_t]$ and calculate the parameters for the AR(2) process ($a_1$, $a_2$ and $\sigma^2$ (the variance of the error term)) using the Yule-Walker equations.

Once I have the parameters which define the AR(2) process I want to simulate a time series. For some covariances the parameter $a_2$ turned out to be very close to zero.

The problematic cases arise when $Cov[X_{t-2},X_{t}]>Cov[X_{t-1},X_{t}]$.
For example:
$Cov[X_{t-2},X_{t}]=0.5$

$Cov[X_{t-1},X_{t}]=0.3$

$Var[X_t]=1$

results in the following AR(2) process:
$$X_t=0.467X_{t-1}+0.0067X_{t-2} + \epsilon_t$$
with $\epsilon_t \sim N(0,0.864)$.

Can this be regarded as an AR(2) process, or is it closer to an AR(1) process given the small parameter $a_2$? Can I pick any covariances and calculate parameters for the AR process, or are there constraints such as $Cov[X_{t-1},X_{t}]>Cov[X_{t-2},X_{t}]$? 
Thanks in advance.
Cheers!